# jQuery sentence case function keeps replacing my text

Tags: html, jquery

I'm trying to make a input sentence case tool but when I type anything different it keeps returning the value="" text.

I'd like to make an exception for pasted or replaced text. So when I type a new value in input it should return that string into sentence case.

Here is the code snippet I've made:

```
function capitalizeFirstLetter(string) {
  return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
}

var title = $("#essay-title").val();
var sentenceCaseTitle = capitalizeFirstLetter(title.toLowerCase());
    //alert( lowerCaseTitle );
function sentencecase() {
    $("#essay-title").trigger("change paste");
    $("#essay-title").val(sentenceCaseTitle);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/c105vedo/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var title = $("#essay-title").val();` is executed immediately on page visit, so it's always empty and not updated. Move that part inside `sentencecase`:

```js
function capitalizeFirstLetter(string) {
  return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
}

function sentencecase() {

  var title = $("#essay-title").val();
  var sentenceCaseTitle = capitalizeFirstLetter(title.toLowerCase());
  $("#essay-title").trigger("change paste");
  $("#essay-title").val(sentenceCaseTitle);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="essay-title" value="TEST TITLE">
<button type="button" onclick="sentencecase()">OK
</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to move the following code into your `sentencecase` function,

```
var title = $("#essay-title").val();
var sentenceCaseTitle = capitalizeFirstLetter(title.toLowerCase());
```

Problem is that if the above code is outside of the function it will only be executed once, so that is why you keep getting the same value.

**Demo**

```js
function capitalizeFirstLetter(string) {
  return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
}

//alert( lowerCaseTitle );
function sentencecase() {
  var title = $("#essay-title").val();
  var sentenceCaseTitle = capitalizeFirstLetter(title.toLowerCase());
  $("#essay-title").trigger("change paste");
  $("#essay-title").val(sentenceCaseTitle);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="essay-title" value="TEST TITLE">
<button type="button" onclick="sentencecase()">OK
</button>
```